# Location of commas after a series of exclamations?

Tags: punctuation, chicago-manual-of-style

In keeping with Chicago Manual of Style, where is it appropriate to place commas in a situation like the following sentence?:

> The Romans seemed happy with the morning’s entertainment, and to shouts of “*Long live Nero!*”, “*Glory be to Caesar!*”, and “*May fortune favour the Emperor!*” two gladiators entered the arena.

Should it be `!”,` like I have it already or `!,”` ?

Comment: @Ben It's fair to ask whether OP had checked the CMoS for themselves, but I'd argue that you're being far too blunt about it and *also* in danger of violating the Code of Conduct. Please try and be a bit less abrasive in future, especially when dealing with new users.

Comment: @irrelevanthh I'm sorry that your first experience on Stack Exchange was so negative. I'm sorry to see you go so soon - and I'm sorry that I didn't see this earlier.

Comment: A final note: lack of research is a valid downvote reason but it is *not* a valid close-vote reason. Feel free to downvote, but please do not vote to close this as, research or no research, it's perfectly on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. It should be outside the quotes "" because if you think about it's just a sequential list. You wouldn't write: "Glory be to Caesar!," the crowd called.